# How to find a pair of lines that should always start with a hyphen but one of the lines does not start with a hyphen by mistake

Tags: regex

How to search for pairs of lines that should always start with a hyphen but one of those lines does not start with a hyphen by mistake.

I want to find all pairs of rows marked in green:
[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxRra.png)

Example text:

491
00:23:34,260 --> 00:23:35,340
- Are you?
- Yes, I am.

492
00:23:34,260 --> 00:23:35,340
- Are you?
Yes, I am.

493
00:23:34,260 --> 00:23:35,340
Are you?
- Yes, I am.

494
00:23:34,260 --> 00:23:35,340
Are you?
Yes, I am.

Some of my attempts. They gave some results, but never quite the desired ones.

`\-\ [a-zA-Z0-9]+(\n|.)*?\-\`

`\-\ [a-zA-Z0-9]+(\n|.)*?^((?!\-).)*$`

`\-\ [a-zA-Z0-9]+(\n|.)*?(^((?!\-).))`

Comment: Can you be more specific than "never quite the desired ones"?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was to think very basal, maybe the following would be enough:

```
^(?!-.+\n-).+\n.+(?=\n\n|\Z)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4htu2c/1)

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(?!-.+\n-)` - Negative lookahead to assert position is not directly followed by a hyphen, 1+ characters other than newline, a newline character and another hyphen;
- `.+\n.+` - Match 1+ characters other than newline, a newline character and again 1+ non-newline characters;
- `(?=\n\n|\Z)` - A positive lookahead to assert position is followed by two consecutive newline characters *or* the end of the text.

This would simply highlight the set of rows that does *not* include two hyphens. However, in your question you do mention you wish to highlight those sets that have *one* hyphen missing. Implicitly this could mean you need one of these two lines to actually still start with an hyphen. If that is the case, try:

```
^(?!-.+\n-)(?=-|.+\n-).+\n.+(?=\n\n|\Z)
```

The only difference is a positive lookahead to assert that there is a hyphen directly or after one line of text. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/okWqZN/1)

Comment: So I spent many, many hours researching and experimenting and the result was a big zero.
And then JvdV writes me a solution within a minute.
And it works!
Thank you very much for your help.
(Scott Hunter: I'm an amateur researcher so even a little progress in my research was progress for me.)

Comment: JvdV: thanks also for the explanation of the character groups used.

Comment: @Pavel, you are welcome. Note I was able to copy your sample data from your OP before you inserted a screenshot. If you want others to play with the sample data you could opt to refert back your choice for a screenshot over markdown data.

Comment: Done for me, JvdV solved my request. His last suggestion below is exactly that.
I just edited the post to make the sample text copyable. And I changed the screenshot to make it clear which pairs of lines to look for and which not.
But anyway, just a formality, I'm happy now.